# Compatibility between XBEE-PRO 900 HP and XBEE SX

Tags: rf, radio, surface-mount, xbee, data-rate

I wanted to use a 900 MHz xbee and I need one side to be surface mount. So I'm thinking of getting an XBEE PRO 900 HP (XBP9B-DMST-002) and an XBEE SX (XB9X-DMUS-001). These devices have the same frequency and network topography but list different rf data rates [[1](https://www.digi.com/pdf/chart_xbee_rf_features.pdf)]. Is it possible to get these device communicating with each other?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The two products are not capable of communicating with each other as they require a different amount of channels to operate over.

[Digi Forum](https://www.digi.com/support/forum/56540/compatibility-between-xbee-pro-900hp-and-xbee-sx-modules)